# Getting confused with MonadBaseControl errors while learning Conduits in Haskell

Tags: http, haskell, conduit

I'm trying go learn about Conduits in Haskell. It sounds interesting, but the types are quickly getting extremely confusing.

I've got the following file written so far: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7991727

Presumably, what it would do is that, given a series of ticker symbols, it would go to Yahoo Finance and download the associated data file. Sounds simple enough.

`getLink` and `extractLink` works great. No problems there.

`downloadContent` is giving me all sorts of compile problems. This source code:

```
downloadContent manager = do
  mx <- await
  case mx of
    Nothing               -> return ()
    Just (sym, Nothing)   -> return ()
    Just (sym, Just link) -> do
      req <- parseUrl link
      res <- http req manager
      responseBody res $$+- sinkFile sym
```

The exact error I'm getting is this:

```
src/suckyahoo.hs:58:21:
    No instance for (MonadBaseControl
                       IO
                       (ConduitM
                          [Char] ([Char], Maybe String) (ResourceT (ResourceT IO))))
      arising from a use of `getLink'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (MonadBaseControl
         IO
         (ConduitM
            [Char] ([Char], Maybe String) (ResourceT (ResourceT IO))))
    In the second argument of `($=)', namely `getLink manager'
    In the first argument of `($$)', namely
      `sourceSyms $= getLink manager'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      sourceSyms $= getLink manager $$ downloadContent manager

src/suckyahoo.hs:58:40:
    No instance for (MonadBaseControl
                       IO
                       (ConduitM
                          (FilePath, Maybe String)
                          void-0.6.1:Data.Void.Void
                          (ResourceT (ResourceT IO))))
      arising from a use of `downloadContent'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (MonadBaseControl
         IO
         (ConduitM
            (FilePath, Maybe String)
            void-0.6.1:Data.Void.Void
            (ResourceT (ResourceT IO))))
    In the second argument of `($$)', namely `downloadContent manager'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      sourceSyms $= getLink manager $$ downloadContent manager
    In the expression:
      do { sourceSyms $= getLink manager $$ downloadContent manager }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What is the insight here that will let me accomplish the intent of the code?

Comment: It this error for this code?  I don't see "urlSource $= getLink manager $$ downloadContent manager" anywhere in the code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to lift your actions to the underlying monad of your conduit:

```
downloadContent manager = do
  mx <- await
  case mx of
    Nothing               -> return ()
    Just (sym, Nothing)   -> return ()
    Just (sym, Just link) -> lift $ do
      req <- parseUrl link
      res <- http req manager
      responseBody res $$+- sinkFile sym
```

Comment: I'm still getting `MonadBaseControl` errors after importing Control.Monad.Trans.Class and using `lift` as you described. Why do I need to lift the block you mentioned above if I didn't need to lift in the getLink function, and is there something else I need to lift?